# list with space into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, list

I have a list of list like that. I want to put it in a dataframe with the same structure as the list (one line per row, separating by the space). But when I use `pd.DataFrame([sub.split(" ") for sub in merged])`, it is separating the first element "Niveaux très haut". Someone can help me?

```
[['Niveaux très haut 51.14 50.85 50.41 49.63 49.01 48.52 48.29 47.97 47.86 48.29 49.47 50.22',
  'Niveaux hauts 50.43 50.15 49.75 49.33 48.74 48.34 48.11 47.80 47.67 47.87 48.65 49.66',
  'Niveaux modérément hauts 49.51 49.47 49.19 48.89 48.39 48.07 47.84 47.55 47.40 47.44 47.94 48.92',
  'Niveaux autour de la moyenne 49.14 49.19 48.96 48.69 48.23 47.95 47.72 47.44 47.30 47.30 47.70 48.60',
  'Niveaux modérément bas 48.78 48.92 48.75 48.49 48.07 47.81 47.60 47.32 47.20 47.17 47.48 48.28',
  'Niveaux bas 47.99 48.31 48.28 48.07 47.73 47.53 47.32 47.03 46.98 46.89 47.00 47.53',
  'Niveaux très bas 47.41 47.83 47.95 47.78 47.47 47.32 47.11 46.77 46.77 46.66 46.62 47.05'],
 ['Niveaux très haut 43.49 43.50 43.38 43.17 42.84 42.49 42.10 41.76 41.74 42.28 42.77 43.29',
  'Niveaux hauts 43.22 43.21 43.09 42.89 42.52 42.15 41.81 41.50 41.43 41.82 42.36 42.93',
  'Niveaux modérément hauts 42.78 42.74 42.65 42.45 42.05 41.73 41.38 41.10 41.00 41.26 41.83 42.42',
  'Niveaux autour de la moyenne 42.56 42.51 42.45 42.23 41.87 41.55 41.19 40.92 40.81 41.05 41.60 42.19',
  'Niveaux modérément bas 42.32 42.28 42.24 42.01 41.69 41.36 40.99 40.74 40.63 40.85 41.37 41.94',
  'Niveaux bas 41.78 41.83 41.82 41.51 41.20 40.87 40.56 40.36 40.26 40.46 40.86 41.35',
  'Niveaux très bas 41.40 41.57 41.52 41.18 40.83 40.54 40.27 40.13 40.05 40.20 40.46 40.93']]
```

**Example of df** :

Niveau|janv|fev|mars|avr|mai|juin|juillet|aou|sept|oct|nov|dec

Niveaux très haut|51.14|50.85|50.41|49.63|49.01|48.52|48.29|47.97|47.86|48.29|49.47|50.22

Niveaux haut|51.14|50.85|50.41|49.63|49.01|48.52|48.29|47.97|47.86|48.29|49.47|50.22

Comment: Can you give a clear snippet example of how you want the output dataframe to look?

Comment: yes ! i just add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think I have what you're looking for here, I just converted the string into a list of column values, that I then converted into a DataFrame. I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this, but this seems to work anyway:

```
import re
import pandas as pd


example_data = [['Niveaux très haut 51.14 50.85 50.41 49.63 49.01 48.52 48.29 47.97 47.86 48.29 49.47 50.22',
              'Niveaux hauts 50.43 50.15 49.75 49.33 48.74 48.34 48.11 47.80 47.67 47.87 48.65 49.66',
              'Niveaux modérément hauts 49.51 49.47 49.19 48.89 48.39 48.07 47.84 47.55 47.40 47.44 47.94 48.92',
              'Niveaux autour de la moyenne 49.14 49.19 48.96 48.69 48.23 47.95 47.72 47.44 47.30 47.30 47.70 48.60',
              'Niveaux modérément bas 48.78 48.92 48.75 48.49 48.07 47.81 47.60 47.32 47.20 47.17 47.48 48.28',
              'Niveaux bas 47.99 48.31 48.28 48.07 47.73 47.53 47.32 47.03 46.98 46.89 47.00 47.53',
              'Niveaux très bas 47.41 47.83 47.95 47.78 47.47 47.32 47.11 46.77 46.77 46.66 46.62 47.05'],
             ['Niveaux très haut 43.49 43.50 43.38 43.17 42.84 42.49 42.10 41.76 41.74 42.28 42.77 43.29',
              'Niveaux hauts 43.22 43.21 43.09 42.89 42.52 42.15 41.81 41.50 41.43 41.82 42.36 42.93',
              'Niveaux modérément hauts 42.78 42.74 42.65 42.45 42.05 41.73 41.38 41.10 41.00 41.26 41.83 42.42',
              'Niveaux autour de la moyenne 42.56 42.51 42.45 42.23 41.87 41.55 41.19 40.92 40.81 41.05 41.60 42.19',
              'Niveaux modérément bas 42.32 42.28 42.24 42.01 41.69 41.36 40.99 40.74 40.63 40.85 41.37 41.94',
              'Niveaux bas 41.78 41.83 41.82 41.51 41.20 40.87 40.56 40.36 40.26 40.46 40.86 41.35',
              'Niveaux très bas 41.40 41.57 41.52 41.18 40.83 40.54 40.27 40.13 40.05 40.20 40.46 40.93']]

final_list_data = []
for i in example_data:
    for j in i:
        title = re.match(r"([A-Z][^\.!?]+)(?= [0-9])", j, re.I) #Find 'words' section of lists
        values = j[len(title[0])+1:].split(' ') #Split rest of values into list
        final_list_data.append([title[0]] + values) #Combine 'words' section back with values in list

#Convert list of lists to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list_data, 
                  columns = ['Niveau','janv','fev','mars','avr','mai','juin','juillet','aou','sept','oct','nov','dec'])
```

If you have any questions, or need something a little different just let me know!

Comment: omg it is working !!! thank you so much I spend a lot of time of this little thing and you helped me a lot!